# MacOS Bash find and echo not working as expected?

Tags: bash, macos, find, rm

I was working on housekeeping an application volume and as a rule of thumb I prepend an `echo` before the `rm` in my `find` command. This has worked for me a very long time until today.

I'm just wondering what is going on if anyone is able to see what if not `find` not respecting `echo`?

```
$ find . -type d -name 'webappsbak' -exec echo rm -rf {} \;
rm -rf ./jetty_ios_2/webappsbak
rm -rf ./jetty/webappsbak
rm -rf ./jetty_0/webappsbak
rm -rf ./jetty_ios/webappsbak
rm -rf ./jetty_ios_1/webappsbak
rm -rf ./jetty_t/webappsbak
rm -rf ./jetty_b/webappsbak
rm -rf ./jetty_b/jetty_0/webappsbak
```

```
$ find . -type d -name 'webappsbak' -exec rm -rf {} \;
find: ./jetty_ios_2/webappsbak: No such file or directory
find: ./jetty/webappsbak: No such file or directory
find: ./jetty_0/webappsbak: No such file or directory
find: ./jetty_ios/webappsbak: No such file or directory
find: ./jetty_ios_1/webappsbak: No such file or directory
find: ./jetty_t/webappsbak: No such file or directory
find: ./jetty_b/webappsbak: No such file or directory
find: ./jetty_b/jetty_0/webappsbak: No such file or directory
```

```
$ bash --version
GNU bash, version 5.0.11(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin19.0.0)
Copyright (C) 2019 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>

This is free software; you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
```

Comment: If your output is not really representative, the cause could be that you have subdirectories within a directory which was already removed. Try adding `-depth` to prevent this from generating an error message.

Comment: @meappy : What happens, if you replace the `rm` by a `ls -ld`? What happes if you manually do a `rm -r ./jetty_ios_2/webappsbak`?

Comment: @meappy : Since the error messages come from `find`, not from `rm`, what does `ls -l ./jetty` show you? Maybe it's a broken symlink ....